# Accord won't start when moisture under hood from rain or snow

Tags: honda, troubleshooting, accord, cranks-wont-run, intermittent-problems

This is a 1999 Honda Accord.

The car has new battery & cables and everything lights up on dash when turning key in ignition, but it will not turn over when we've had rain or snow.

The weather has been dry last 4 days & car starts every time. Someone suggested crack in coil packs possibly? What could explain this behavior?

Comment: If it won't even turn over the problem is not with coils or anything else in the ignition system.  There's a bad connection in the starter circuit, or a bad battery connection.  I've never had a Honda tho.

Comment: @Terri what do you mean by turn over? Do you hear relays and the starter engaging and turning the motor? If it's just clicking, you should go get your battery checked even if it's new. It could be defective.

Comment: definitely explain what you mean by "turn over".  Some people mean "start" and some mean "crank"

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend replacing the distributor cap, distributor rotor (usually sold together), and coil pack as your friend already suggested. When there is excessive moisture in the air, making an electrical connection between two materials (as is what happens in a distributor) becomes more difficult. Normally this is not an issue because the distributor cap and rotor are in close enough proximity to transmit the charge, but as those contacts wear over time it becomes more difficult for the electricity to bridge that gap (thanks SolarMike for the correction).

Comment: Does a 99 Accord really have a mechanical ignition system?  I'd expect it to be fully electronic, right?

Comment: The rotor has a physical contact with the "king" lead via the brush but there is an air gap between the rotor end and each of the pins for each of the cylinder leads. The only time I saw evidence of any contact was when the distributor shaft had excessive play...

Answer (score 1):

Check the distributor and the sensors on the throttle body (mass air flow, throttle position, etc). You can put dielectric grease on their electronic connectors and around the parts to keep moisture from getting in there.

I highly recommend getting a cheap OBDII scan tool like this one - http://amzn.to/2F9m1Jo - that connects to your sell phone with a $3 app. The ECU/PCM should tell you what is wrong and why it is not starting. That should work fine on your '99.